# PHP/PDO : No result if a column = 0?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a very simple function to check in the DB if we know an Artist (based on a unique ID) and if it's the case, I want to collect his infos :

```
function isArtistKnown($id_artist){
    global $pdo;

    $isKnownQuery = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM artistes WHERE IDArtiste = '$id_artist'");
    if($isKnownQuery->rowCount() > 0){
        $KnownArtiste = $isKnownQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $KnownArtiste;
    }else{
        return $isKnownQuery->errorInfo();
    }
}
```

The problem is following :

If the IDArtiste is known and another colmun called "last_tweet' (INT50) equals 0 then the PDO finds 1 result and $KnownArtiste is filled.
Now, If the IDArtiste is known but the colum "last_tweet" != 0 then the PDO doens't find any result (and errorInfo() equals 0000, which means : no error).

Do you have an idea where the problem comes from ?

Comment: It means nothing matches your condition, no rows returned!

Comment: Have you run the same query in another mysql client? (Also the could looks suspicious not to escape $id_artist, and my guess would be that this is an integer and shouldn't need `''` quotes, you might also look into prepared statements)

Comment: @senk I confirm that there is a match. The IDArtiste stays always the same and it's the only one in the SQL condition.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) states :

> PDO::query() executes an SQL statement in a single function call,
> returning the result set **(if any)** returned by the statement as a
> PDOStatement object.

Which means, if there's no match, it returns no rows!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting directly from the PHP [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) page:

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding
>   PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

You can't use rowCount with SELECTs. Use this instead:

```
function isArtistKnown($id_artist){
    global $pdo;
    //If you don't use prepared statements, a kitten and a puppy die somewhere
    $isKnownQuery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM artistes WHERE IDArtiste = :ida");
    $isKnownQuery->bindValue(':ida', $id_artist);
    $isKnownQuery->execute(); 
    $KnownArtiste = $isKnownQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if(isset($KnownArtiste->IDArtiste)){
        return $KnownArtiste;
    }else{
        //Actually, in this case there's no error, just no artist
        //so i'd use
        return null;
        //instead of
        //return $isKnownQuery->errorInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, the prepared statements is better. However the problem is the same : 1 match if 'last_tweet" = 0. No match if 'last_tweet' != 0 
Of course the IdArtiste is always the same, I don't change it when I try differents values of 'last_tweet'.

Comment: I need to see the actual data in your table, because last_tweet has no bearing whatsoever in the query you posted.

Comment: The column last_tweet is '0' by default or a timestamp.

Comment: @Cyc : please do a `var_dump($KnownArtiste); die;` before the if and tell me what you get

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to return `errorInfo()` it'll always contain data whether there is an error or not. You should be returning a friendly user message to state that there are no rows  found (the artist is not known to you)

```
function isArtistKnown($id_artist){
    global $pdo;

    $isKnownQuery = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM artistes WHERE IDArtiste = '$id_artist'");
    if ($isKnownQuery->rowCount() === 0){
        return false;
    }
    $KnownArtiste = $isKnownQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $KnownArtiste
}
```

and validate:

```
$Validate = isArtistKnown(0);
if ($Validate === false){
 echo "Artist is Not Known";
}else{
 //Work with your data
}
```

Comment: rowCount can't be used with select statements. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php